# Peer certificate CN=`stream.twitter.com' did not match expected CN=`199.16.156.217'

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, twitter-streaming-api, php-openssl

I was trying to develop a twitter streaming application on my AWS EC2 machine. The OS platform is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and I have downgraded the PHP version to 5.6.28-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1

When I run the twitter streaming application on this server, I am getting the following errors.

```
Warning: fsockopen(): Peer certificate CN=`stream.twitter.com' did not match expected CN=`199.16.156.217' in /var/www/html/myapp/streamer/twitterstreamer.php on line 620

Warning: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/html/myapp/streamer/twitterstreamer.php on line 620

 Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://199.16.156.217:443 (Unknown error) in /var/www/html/myapp/streamer/twitterstreamer.php on line 620
```

The same code is running without any issues in another two machines (one is AWS EC2 and the another is a godaddy server).

All the ports in the current EC2 machine is open now and the `SSL` version is `OpenSSL/1.0.2g` the `openssl` section is having the following value.

[`openssl` section - phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BMGQ.png)

Can someone help me to find where the exact issue is ?

Comment: *"The same code is running without any issues in another two machine..."* What code? You have not posted any.

Comment: a long shot... is the IP correct?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved with the clue fro the first error.
`Warning: fsockopen(): Peer certificate CN='stream.twitter.com' did not match expected CN='199.16.156.217' in /var/www/html/myapp/streamer/twitterstreamer.php on line 620`

In PHP 5.6.x, the value of openssl `VERIFY_PEER` is true by default. The system will first fetch the certificate from the peer and matches with ours. In my application, I was connecting with the IP and the URL in the fetched certificate is `stream.twitter.com`. This was the issue.

Changing IP in the `fsockopen` to `stream.twitter.com` solved my issue.

PHP versions prior to 5.6, the default value of `VERIFY_PEER` is false and this is why the same code running on my other instances.

Comment: Yep, it's called SNI (Server Name Indication) - your client has to verify that the certificate it receives was issued to the hostname requested. Otherwise, you don't know if the certificate wasn't replaced for nefarious reasons; and also because a single server can have multiple hostnames, each with separate certificates.